# How to change the state of a PopupSwitchMenuItem in gnome extension

Tags: gnome-shell-extensions

I am working with a gnome extension which has a toggle switch on its panel popup menu.
I have bound a keyboard shortcut to the same setting, so I want to change the state of the toggle to  reflect what happens with the keyboard shortcut.

the toggle comes from code like this:

```
let toggle = new PopupSwitchMenuItem(desc, active);
```

and I can save a reference to toggle so that is known to the code that handles the short cut. 
But I don't know how to change the state.
I hoped toggle.set_state(true) might work, but whatever object toggle is, it does not support set_state()

Answer (score 0):

Right, well I found a the correct javascript libary.
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/blob/master/js/ui/popupMenu.js
and from there, this works:

```
 toggle._switch.state = true;
```

EDIT: Better solution from Gnome dev Florian Müllner

ie `toggle.setToggleState(bool)`

It’s setToggleState(), see https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/blob/master/js/ui/popupMenu.js#L419

https://discourse.gnome.org/t/newbie-shell-extension-coder-how-to-i-set-the-state-of-a-switch-created-with-popupswitchmenuitem/3370?u=tim_richardson